# App crashes because I am searching for a non-existent Index in my ArrayList. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, android, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I have read all of the documentation on IOExceptions and what it means when they are produced. I am aware that I am searching for en Index in my ArrayList that doesn't exist, thus producing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`. I have consulted the following documentation and posts to try to handle the problem on my own, but haven't been successful. After doing this thorough research I hope someone can help me elude this problem. I have legitimately looked through many posts of similar type problems on here to alone try to resolve my error, but haven't been able to come to the right conclusion.

[What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it). 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

I have tried put en `if` statement around the `addressList` for example, and a `toast` message warning the user that they have to refine their search. When searching for most places on the map, the results come out fine and a marker is placed on the map at that specific location. When I search for Paris though, I get the exception and like I said I have wrapped it in an `if` statement and other methods, but no success.

```java
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        String location = searchView.getQuery().toString();
        List<Address> addressList = null;

        if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivityPublisher.this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location).draggable(true));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));

        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.e.events.Map.MapsActivityPublisher$1.onQueryTextSubmit(MapsActivityPublisher.java:62)
        at android.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1270)
        at android.widget.SearchView.access$1000(SearchView.java:99)
        at android.widget.SearchView$7.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1247)
        at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:6453)
        at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:138)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:363)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: *I have tried put en if statement around the addressList* - your code doesn't have anything of that sort

Comment: @user7 I took it off because it didn't work... I did the ```if``` statement around ```Address address = …``` , but app kept crashing so I took it off

Comment: This or (`||`) statement should be an and (`&&`), since you want to check both cases: `if (location != null || !location.equals(""))`. Currently an empty string will pass the first check, so not be subjected to the second check.

Comment: @JakeSteam just tried it... Still crashes

Comment: You need to show more of your code. `geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);` is either throwing an error or returning an empty list.

Comment: @JakeSteam well, that much I understand. But what can I do to fix it? The location isn't specific enough, so it comes back empty. How can I make it so that either the ```toast``` message shows and app doesn't crash so user knows to fix search or something else

Comment: @JMB Just add `if (addressList.size > 0) {` check around the 4 lines that handle the address? Can then add an `else` to do whatever you want.

Comment: @JakeSteam okay man, seems to work. I did the same thing before, but substituting ```if (addressList != null) { … ```and then  ```toasting``` it, but kept crashing. Think it's relatively similar resolution. But anyways, seems to work for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check `null` and `empty` before get data from `ArrayList`

```
if (location != null && !location.equals("")) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivityPublisher.this);
    try {
        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(addressList != null && !addressList.isEmpty()) {
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location).draggable(true));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));
    }

}
```

Comment: Why ```&&``` and not ```||```?

Comment: `||` allows both `null` and `empty` to execute the code.

Comment: In case of `null` first condition `location != null` return `false` but `!location.equals("")` return `true`. So code block execute

Comment: In case of `empty` first condition `location != null` return `true`. So code block execute

Comment: Okay. I just need one of the conditions to be true, bot both to return a valid query. But thanks. Seems to be working now